# Android retrofit jackson wrong query parameter serialization if turkish language

Tags: android, jackson, kotlin, retrofit, turkish

For example, I have an enum object `FruitEnum.FRUIT`:

```
enum class FruitEnum {
    @JsonProperty("fruit") FRUIT
}
```

which I want to pass as query parameter in my request:

```
@GET("fruit_request")
fun fruitRequest(
        @Query("fruit_param") fruitParam: FruitEnum 
): Single<FruitResponse>
```

If I switch to turkish language on my phone letter `i` from `@JsonProperty("fruit")` will be serialized as `%C4%B1`, which is, as far as I know, percent encoding for URIs of turkish letter `ı` ([dotless i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I)). However, I still need it to be just `fruit` instead of `fru%C4%B1t`. What can I do about it?

Comment: So, you need to replace Turkish letters with English ones. But I can't see why on earth you may need this.

Comment: No, actually what is happening is that when turkish language enabled english letter `i` gets automatically replaced (I don't want this) with turkish dotless i, then it is getting converted to `%C4%B1` somewhere on Retrofit's or OkHTTP's side. I don't understand this because I specified latin word `fruit` in `@JsonProperty("fruit")` without any turkish letters.

Comment: Your `furit_param`'s value contains non-latin characters inputted by user. They are prohibited by HTTP, so it's absolutely normal that they are being encoded. Every web-server/web-framework handling requests on the other side will decode them back.